# Days between dates if statement pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Attempting to add column in a dataframe that returns a value if days between dates in two separate columns exceed a certain amount.

```
if (cust_ledger['Posting Date_x'].shift(14, freq=pd.datetools.Day)) < datime.now():
```

I get the following error on the above line

```
NotImplementedError: Not supported for type Int64Index
```

Comment: have also attempted if (cust_ledger['Posting Date_x'].DateOffset(days=14)) < datime.now():

Answer (score 0):

How's about:

`import pandas as pd`

`cust_ledger['newCol'] = cust_ledger['dataSource'][cust_ledger['date1']-cust_ledger['date2'] > pd.Timedelta(14)]`

This code will create a new column 'newCol' containing data from 'dataSource' column, for rows where 'date1' - 'date2' > 14 days.  Probably will contain NaN for rows not meeting this condition.  Should be possible to swap cust_ledger['date2'] with `datetime.now()`